# Putting EC2 Instance public Ip in Ansible Host File

Tags: ansible

Hey I am new to Ansible and working with it for a project one of the steps is to input our rhel7 instance public ip address into the Ansible hosts file. We weren't given any other instruction and I wanted to make sure I did so correctly (line 11 of my Hosts File), any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Hosts File

```
# This is the default ansible 'hosts' file.
#
# It should live in /etc/ansible/hosts
#
#   - Comments begin with the '#' character
#   - Blank lines are ignored
#   - Groups of hosts are delimited by [header] elements
#   - You can enter hostnames or ip addresses
#   - A hostname/ip can be a member of multiple groups

# Ex 1: Ungrouped hosts, specify before any group headers.
3.82.200.205
## green.example.com
## blue.example.com
## 192.168.100.1
## 192.168.100.10

# Ex 2: A collection of hosts belonging to the 'webservers' group

##[webservers]

## alpha.example.org
## beta.example.org
## 192.168.1.100
## 192.168.1.110

# If you have multiple hosts following a pattern you can specify
# them like this:

## www[001:006].example.com

# Ex 3: A collection of database servers in the 'dbservers' group

## [dbservers]
##
## db01.intranet.mydomain.net
## db02.intranet.mydomain.net
## 10.25.1.56
## 10.25.1.57

# Here's another example of host ranges, this time there are no
# leading 0s:

## db-[99:101]-node.example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add-on Vladimir's answer, the servers created in AWS normally come with Elastic IP and it can be changed after you restart the server

So you need to make it dynamic inventory when your system becomes bigger and more complex, take an example from this article: https://medium.com/happy5/aws-dynamic-inventory-and-ansible-thank-god-i-can-sleep-more-4d2aeadbc6f. This approach works for me and I use it to manage more than 50 AWS EC2 instances with dynamic IPs

And looks like there is AWS plugin here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.html, I haven't give a try on this solution yet, but it may have some advantage as this is from Ansible official document

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's correct. Here is a link to [Working with Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) (for the record).